# $f$ irreducible iff Galois group acts transitively on roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $f\in{Q[t]}$ be of degree $>0$, with no repeated roots, and let L be the splitting field for F. Show that $f\in{Q}$ (rationals) is irreducible iff for any $a,b\in{Root_f(L)}$ there is $G\in{Gal(L,Q)}$ such that $G(a)=b$.

A proof that piqued my interest was [the simple proof in Theorem 24.3 here](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111101001/downloads/Lecture24.pdf). However, I do not understand when they write:

> Let $g(r)=h(s)=0$, where $r,s\in{Q^a}$ (algebraic closure of rationals). Let $G\in{Gal_f}$ be a permutation which maps $r$ to $s$. We may assume that $g(x)$ is irreducible. But then $s$ has to be a root of $g(x)$.

Specifically, what I do not understand is how one can be certain such a mapping in $Gal_f$ exists/why this then implies $s$ must be a root of $g(x)$?

Comment: I only see $F^a$ instead of $Q^a$

Comment: @KennyLau Here I am assuming $F=Q$ (rationals)...

Comment: The link is outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Why the algebraic closure**: if we fix an algebraic closure, then things become more canonical, e.g. there is a unique splitting field (inside the algebraic closure) for any polynomial, unique normal closure, etc. Most importantly, a polynomial $f$ has exactly $\deg f$ roots (up to multiplicity).
2. **Why such a mapping exists**: by assumption, since $r$ and $s$ are roots of $f$.
3. **Why must $s$ be a root of $g$**: Let $g = \sum a_i t^i$. We know that $g(r) = 0$, so $\sum a_i r^i = 0$. Now, $G$ is a field homomorphism, so $G(\sum a_i r^i) = \sum a_i G(r)^i$, but the latter is just $g(G(r))$, i.e. $g(s)$, so $g(s) = 0$.

Comment: In the proof $g$ is assumed to be irreducible. Where is that used?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be roots of $f$. Since $f$ is irreducible, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]=\deg f$, so there exist an isomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\to\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$, sending $\alpha$ to $\beta$ and fixing $\mathbb{Q}$. This isomorphism can be uniquely extended to an automorphism $\sigma$ on $\Omega_{\mathbb{Q}}^f$, and so we have $\sigma\in\text{Gal}(f)$ with $\sigma(\alpha)=\sigma(\beta)$.